# textCapSentences works on emulator but doesn't work on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-edittext

In my app, for particular `EditText`, I want first letter of the sentence to be Capital/Upper case. So I used `android:inputType="textCapSentences"`.

The strange thing is this works on emulator, but doesn't work on emulator. I even tried `android:capitalize="sentences"` even though it's deprecated, but it didn't work.

Related facts:

- Emulator OS: 4.0.3
- Real device OS: 4.0.4
- App minSdk version: 2.3.3

I also tried with emulator with 4.2.2 OS but the result was same.

Can anyone suggest anything I can try? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which device did you test against? Did you try with different device/model?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have only 1 device with me right now i.e. Micromax Canvas A100

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22321964/1939564 check this might help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried setting this programmatically?

```
EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Moreover, you have to be aware that "Input method editors (IMEs) do not have to honor all the settings in android:inputType. Those are suggestions or requests that you are making, not demands."([android:inputType="textCapSentences" Not Always Honored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026986/androidinputtype-textcapsentences-not-always-honored))